# a few with antibodies that reacted to PF4, and those reacted relatively weakly

Tags: phrase-meaning

"Those reacted relatively weakly" to what? To PF4 as well? It seems to have a possibility that "reacted relatively weakly" is simply referring to a weak immune response. I am not sure.

> Initial studies by Greinacher’s team, posted as a preprint, don’t support that theory either. Among more than 200 patients who had recovered from COVID-19, **they found only a few with antibodies that reacted to PF4, and those reacted relatively weakly.** More importantly, Greinacher says, the platelet-activating antibodies isolated from VITT patients did not react to the coronavirus spike protein. At a press conference on Friday, Greinacher called the finding “fantastic news for the vaccination program.”

> Source: [Science](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2021/04/hard-choices-emerge-link-between-astrazeneca-vaccine-and-rare-clotting-disorder-becomes)

Answer (score 1):

> Among more than 200 patients who had recovered from COVID-19, they
> found only a few with antibodies that reacted to PF4, and those
> reacted relatively weakly

Among more than 200 patients who had recovered from COVID-19, they found only a few patients with antibodies that reacted to PF4, and those antibodies reacted relatively weakly to PF4.

Comment: So "those" refers to "those antibodies" rather than "those/some patients"?

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is a bit vague, but I would read it to mean that among the 200 patients, they found only a few patients with antibodies that reacted to PF4, and those patients had a mild reaction. The antibodies reacted weakly to PF4.